# How to deploy an artifact (Maven) to Github package using github actions

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

I am trying to write github actions pipeline for a simple Spring Boot Application using Maven as the build tool. Build and validations are successful, but deployment of the Jar to Github Registry fails with error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project space-management-system: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access registry=https://maven.pkg.github.com/Pranav3105/osmosis with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access registry=https://maven.pkg.github.com/Pranav3105/osmosis using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR]       role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
[ERROR]   roleHint: registry=https
```

Here's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mindtree</groupId>
    <artifactId>space-management-system</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>space-management-system</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       .........
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <properties>
                ...sonar properties.....
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sonar</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <distributionManagement>

        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>pranav3105</name>
            <url>registry=https://maven.pkg.github.com/Pranav3105/osmosis</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

and here's my workflow file created:

```
name: Master Branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'

jobs:

  test:
    name: Test - Units & Integrations
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11.0.4
      - name: Maven Package
        run: mvn -B clean package -DskipTests
      - name: Maven Verify
        run: mvn -B clean verify -DskipTests

  sonar:
    name: Test - SonarCloud Scan
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11.0.4
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        run: mvn -B clean verify -DskipTests -Psonar -Dsonar.login=${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  artifact:
    name: Publish - GitHub Packages
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    needs: [test, sonar]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11.0.4
      - name: Publish artifact on GitHub Packages
        run: mvn -B -e -X clean deploy -DskipTests
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I have also tried putting servers tag in settings.xml, passing it as the argument during maven deploy phase but that also fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should remove "registry=" from the start of distributionManagement > repository > url in your pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>github</id>
     <name>pranav3105</name>
     <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/Pranav3105/osmosis</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

look at [this repo](https://github.com/MRtecno98/SpigotCommons), it's a good sample.